# How to retrieve specific values from array with multiple PHP for loops?

Tags: php, html, arrays, for-loop

I have been working on trying to retrieve specific results from a PHP for loop without success.

My objective is to run a loop on an array and to pull the specific value each time if it exists within the array. I am able to run the first loop and retrieve a value, however, when I run the second for function it retrieves the exact same number. I haven't been able to figure out why. E.g. The first loop returns the value of 6, but so does the second loop. I am trying to retrieve 6 if it exists from the first loop and 7 if it exists in the second loop. 7 is located in the array, so it should return 6 in the first for statement and 7 on the second.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($final_data); $i++) {
    $check_sector = $final_data[$i]['sector'];
    $check_image = $final_data[$i]['image'];
      if($final_data[$i]['sector'] == 6){
        echo "<div id='6' class='w3-button w3-ripple grid-item-sector' onclick='getSector(this.id)'>"
        . "<div id='ss6' style='position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-image: url(" . $check_image . ");'></div>"
                ."<div id='s6' class='overlay' ></div></div>";
        break;
      }else{
        echo "<div id='6' class='w3-button w3-ripple grid-item-sector' onclick='getSector(this.id)'>"
        ."<div id='s6' class='overlay' ></div></div>";
        break;
      }
  }

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($final_data); $i++) {
    $check_sector = $final_data[$i]['sector'];
    $check_image = $final_data[$i]['image'];
      if($final_data[$i]['sector'] == 7){
        echo "<div id='7' class='w3-button w3-ripple grid-item-sector' onclick='getSector(this.id)'>"
        . "<div id='ss7' style='position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-image: url(" . $check_image . ");'></div>"
                ."<div id='s7' class='overlay' ></div></div>";
        break;
      }else{
        echo "<div id='7' class='w3-button w3-ripple grid-item-sector' onclick='getSector(this.id)'>"
        ."<div id='s7' class='overlay' ></div></div>";
          break;
      }
  }
```

Comment: hmmm it looks correct. I would try debugging it by doing something like var_dump($final_data); right before it starts echoing to see what it's doing under the hood.. Also how are you concluding it's doing 6 both times? Are you looking at the ID of the echoed div?

Comment: I have been using print_r to see what the value is when it runs to figure out what the result is. Here are the var_dump results for $final_data when I put the var_dump before the echo: array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["sector"]=>
    int(6)
    ["image"]=>
    string(12) "img/iron.png"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["sector"]=>
    int(7)
    ["image"]=>
    string(12) "img/iron.png"
  }

Comment: And how are you determining it’s doing 6 both times? I noticed onclick is passing in “this.id” what is that??

Comment: The first function catches the 6 and echos the first statement, the second function moves to the else statement which I believe means that it didn't catch the 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get to the second foreach loop, it’s hitting the first element in the array first.

So it’s saying is 6==7? No, so it goes to the else echo statement.

Then you have a break so it gives up and never checks the second element in the array which is the 7.

Comment: Essentially break means break out of this loop and don’t check anymore of the elements

Comment: If instead you meant continue on to the next iteration of this loop, you would want to replace “break;” with “continue;”